# mysql timeout error in rails 3 when using delete_all and make! in step definition

Tags: activerecord, transactions, ruby-on-rails-3, cucumber

I'm using following construct in a cucumber step definition.

```
Given "I have following stuff" do
   Model.delete_all

   list.each { |i| Model.make!(:name => i) } 
end
```

(make! is from machinist 2).

Above step fails with INSERT statement timeout. When I open up a console for test, environment, I can execute each statement without an issue. Also, if I disable transactional features timeout goes away.

Can anyone please help me fix this? (This ran without an issue with rails 2.x)

(Database MySQL)

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Comment: Mysql2::Error: Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction: INSERT INTO `model` (values...)
  SQL (0.8ms)  ROLLBACK
  SQL (39.5ms)  ROLLBACK

Comment: Sorry about the late reply. Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This turned out be an issue with machinist beta version I was using. I'm not 100% sure what was wrong, but when I used pure ActiveRecord code to create the objects, instead of make! it worked.

Then I switched to Factory_Girl instead of machinist, and now it works fine.